# thread asynctask and listview

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Hi guys i have a problem with my code... i have moved myTask into Splashscreen.java..
this is arrivi.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View arrivi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arrivi, container, false); 


       return arrivi;
    }

    public void CheckRow(){

        ListView list;
        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= thread; i++) {

            RowItem item = new RowItem(Compagnia[i], CodiceVolo[i], Citta[i],OraPrevista[i],  OraStimata[i], StatoVolo[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
            System.out.println(CodiceVolo[i]);
        } 
        list=(ListView)arrivi.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

line 103 is

```
  list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
```

Comment: It seems that CheckRow is in a fragment. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using getActivity(), you should be getting the layout from the Fragment.getView().

**Update**

So, you're launching your AsyncTask in the onCreate of your Activity. The AsyncTask's onPostExecute can get called before your Fragment's onCreateView gets called, which is what I suspect is happening here; hence the null pointer. In general, these are some of the nuances of using AsyncTasks.

You have several options:

1. Use [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) in favor of AsyncTasks
2. Launch the AsyncTask from your Fragment, which guarantees the Fragment to be attached and active.
3. In CheckRow, make sure you're Fragment is active before performing the work.
4. Use retained fragments to perform background processing

Checkout [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) link for more info.

Comment: list=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
null pointer is!! :( arrivi is a fragment. If i put class asynctask into class arrivi, it's works